# Trouble with SQL recursive join in DB2

Tags: sql, recursion, db2, recursive-query

I'm relatively novice with writing SQL and can't seem to get the correct output from my recursive statement. The source table is something like this:

```
SEQUENCE    TEXT        CATEGORY
1           This is     apples
2           a complete  apples
3           sentence.   apples
```

The output I'm trying to get is:

```
CATEGORY    TEXT
apples      This is a complete sentence.
```

However, the result I'm getting is:

```
CATEGORY    TEXT
apples      This is a complete
```

I unable to essentially concatenate more than 2 lines. I think it has something to do with the count I've set up in the recursive part of my WITH statement.

```
WITH rquery (category, sequence, sentence)
         AS (SELECT base.category, base.sequence, base.text
             FROM myTable base
             WHERE sequence = 1
             Union ALL
             SELECT t1.category, t1.sequence, sentence || ' ' || t1.text
             FROM rquery t0, myTable t1
             WHERE t0.category = t1.category And t0.sequence + 1 = t1.sequence
             ) 
SELECT * FROM rquery WHERE sequence in (SELECT MAX(sequence) FROM rquery);
```

If you remove the last WHERE clause, the results shows what's going on but I can't seem to find a solution to get it right. Here's without the last WHERE clause:

```
CATEGORY    SEQUENCE    SENTENCE
apples      1           This is
apples      2           This is a complete
apples      3           This is a complete
```

Comment: You are selecting from 2 different tables: `myTable base` and `hfcom.ordcom t1` -- are you sure data are consistent in both?

Comment: Missed that, I corrected it and yes, it's the same table.

Comment: A couple of things here - don't use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax.  Instead, always explicitly list your joins, and move as many conditions as possible to the relevant `ON` clause.  You may also want to try joining `rquery` to an aggregated subquery on the original table, as the optimizer may have a better time fulfilling `MAX` via an index.

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding explicit joins. Can you explain more about "joining `rquery` to an aggregated subquery" and how that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how TEXT is defined, the final value might be truncated and then, depending on the client you use to run the query, you may never know about that.

Try casting `TEXT` to a longer `VARCHAR`, e.g.

```
WITH rquery (category, sequence, sentence)
     AS (SELECT base.category, base.sequence, CAST( base.text AS VARCHAR(100))
         FROM myTable base
         ...
```

The resulting data type of `sentence` must be large enough to fit the longest possible concatenation of `text`s.

Comment: And if this is relevant for anyone reading, it's a recordset through ADODB connection in Excel VBA.